# Why do function "have memory" in REBOL?

Tags: function, rebol, rebol2

In rebol I have written this very simple function:

```
make-password: func[Length] [
    chars: "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890"
    password: ""
    loop Length [append password (pick chars random Length)]
    password
    ]
```

When I run this multiple times in a row things get really confusing:

```
loop 5 [print make-password 5]
```

Gives (for example) this output:

- TWTQW
- TWTQWWEWRT
- TWTQWWEWRTQWWTW
- TWTQWWEWRTQWWTWQTTQQ
- TWTQWWEWRTQWWTWQTTQQTRRTT

It looks like the function memorised the past executions and stored the result and than used it again!

I did not ask this!

I would like to have output similar to the following:

- IPS30
- DQ6BE
- E70IH
- XGHBR
- 7LMN5

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: @Joachim No, it behaves exactly the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good question.

Rebol code is actually best thought of as a very stylized data structure.  That data structure "happens to be executable".  But you need to understand how it works.

For instance, from @WiseGenius's suggestion:

```
make-password: func[Length] [
    chars: "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890"
    password: copy ""
    loop Length [append password (pick chars random Length)]
    password
]
```

Take a look at the block containing `append password...`.  That block is "imaged" there; what it really looks like under the hood is:

```
chars: **pointer to string! 0xSSSSSSS1**
password: copy **pointer to string! 0xSSSSSSS2**
loop Length **pointer to block! 0xBBBBBBBB**
password
```

All series are working this way when they are loaded by the interpreter.  Strings, blocks, binaries, paths, parens, etc.  Given that it's "turtles all the way down", if you follow through to that pointer, the block 0xBBBBBBBB is internally:

```
append password **pointer to paren! 0xPPPPPPPP**
```

One result of this is that a series can be referenced (and hence "imaged") in multiple places:

```
>> inner: [a]

>> outer: reduce [inner inner]
[[a] [a]]

>> append inner 'b

>> probe outer
[[a b] [a b]]
```

This can be a source of confusion for newcomers, but once you understand the data structure you begin to know when to use COPY.

So you've noticed an interesting implication of this with functions.  Consider this program:

```
foo: func [] [
    data: []
    append data 'something
]

source foo

foo
foo

source foo
```

That produces a possibly-surprising result:

```
foo: func [][
    data: [] 
    append data 'something
]

foo: func [][
    data: [something something] 
    append data 'something
]
```

We call `foo` a couple of times, it appears that *the function's source code is changing as we do so*.  It is, in a sense, self-modifying code.

If this bothers you, there are tools in R3-Alpha for attacking it.  You can use PROTECT to protect function bodies from modification, and even create your own alternatives to routines like FUNC and FUNCTION that will do it for you.  (PFUNC?  PFUNCTION?)  In Rebol version 3 you can write:

```
pfunc: func [spec [block!] body [block!]] [
    make function! protect/deep copy/deep reduce [spec body]
]

foo: pfunc [] [
    data: []
    append data 'something
]

foo
```

When you run that you get:

```
*** ERROR
** Script error: protected value or series - cannot modify
** Where: append foo try do either either either -apply-
** Near: append data 'something
```

So that forces you to copy series.  It also points out that FUNC is just a function! itself, and so is FUNCTION.  You can make your own generators.

This may break your brain and you may run screaming saying "this is not any sane way to write software".  Or maybe you will say "my God, it's full of stars."  Reactions may vary.  But it is fairly fundamental to the "trick" that powers the system and gives it wild flexibility.

*(Note: The [Ren-C branch of Rebol3](https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c) has fundamentally made it so that function bodies--and source series in general--are locked by default.  If one wants a static variable in a function, you can say **`foo: func [x <static> accum (copy "")] [append accum x | return accum]`** and the function will accumulate state in `accum` across calls.)*

I'll also suggest paying close attention to what is actually happening on each run.  Before you've run the `foo` function, *data has no value*.  What happens is each time we execute the function and the evaluator sees a SET-WORD! followed by a series value, it performs the assignment to the variable.

```
data: **pointer to block! 0xBBBBBBBB**
```

After that assignment, you'll have *two* references to the block in existence.  One is its existence in the code structure that was established at LOAD time, before the function had ever been run.  The second reference is the one that was stored into the data variable.  It's through this second reference that you are modifying this series.

And notice that *data will be reassigned each time the function is run*.  But reassigned to the same value over and over again...that original block pointer!  This is why you have to COPY if you want a fresh block on every run.

Grasping the underlying simplicity in the evaluator rules is part of the giddy interesting-ness.  This is how the simplicity was dressed up to make a language (in a way you could twist to your own means).  For instance, there is no "multiple-assignment":

```
a: b: c: 10
```

That's just the evaluator hitting **a:** as a SET-WORD! symbol and saying "okay, let's associate the variable **a** in its binding context with whatever the next complete expression produces.".  **b:** does the same.  **c:** does the same but hits a terminal because of the integer value 10...and then *also* evaluates to 10.  So it looks like multiple-assignment.

So just remember that the original instance of a series literal is the one hanging in the loaded source.  If the evaluator ever gets around to doing this kind of SET-WORD! or SET assignment, it will borrow the pointer to that literal in the source to poke into the variable.  It's a mutable reference.  You (or the abstractions you design) can make it immutable with PROTECT or PROTECT/DEEP, and you can make it not-a-reference with COPY or COPY/DEEP.

---

**Related Note**

Some argue that you should never write **copy []**...because (a) you might get in the habit of forgetting to write the COPY, and (b) you are making an unused series every time you do it.  That "blank series template" gets allocated, has to be scanned by the garbage collector, and no one ever actually touches it.

If you write **make block! 10** (or whatever size you want to preallocate the block) you avoid the issue, save a series, and offer a sizing hint.

Comment: It looks like your code is broken: it gives `Script Error: function expected body argument of type: block` (I am using REBOL 2.7 View).

Comment: @Caridorc Rebol3 redefined the meaning of FUNCTION to be what Rebol2 had called FUNCT *(which is [in line with Red](http://www.red-lang.org/p/contributions.html), also)*.  I tend to find the Rebol3 function, which does automatic gathering of SET-WORD! elements in the body as **/local** parameters, to be the more elegant name and best default behavior for new users, so I tend to type it vs. the lower-level primitive FUNC.  But I have changed it to FUNC in my example in case the example is being considered in both Rebol2 and Rebol3.

Comment: @Caridorc Note also you now have the points needed for access to [Rebol and Red SO chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red)

Comment: @Memophenon asks *The sizing hint has always puzzled me. Are there any recommendations for what to choose here in case you have no idea of the final magnitude?*  I feel that the encoding of meaningless information in code is a BadThing(tm), and I'm not a fan of inconsistency either.  So that is why I [pushed for this proposal](http://curecode.org/rebol3/ticket.rsp?id=2139&cursor=1).  If you wanted you could create a little helper called **make-block** that took no parameters by default and then **make-block/capacity** with an integer refinement.

Answer (score 2):

By default, this notation doesn't copy the value of the string `""` to `password`. Instead, it sets `password` to point to that string which sits in the body block of the function. So when you perform `append` on `password` you're actually appending to that string which it points to, which is sitting in your function's body block. You're actually changing part of the body block of the function. To see what's going on, you can use `??` examine your function to watch what happens to it each time you use it:

```
make-password: func[Length] [
    chars: "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890"
    password: ""
    loop Length [append password (pick chars random Length)]
    password
]

loop 5 [
    print make-password 5
    ?? make-password
]
```

This should give you something like:

```
TWTQW
make-password: func [Length][
    chars: "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890"
    password: "TWTQW"
    loop Length [append password (pick chars random Length)]
    password
]
TWTQWWEWRT
make-password: func [Length][
    chars: "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890"
    password: "TWTQWWEWRT"
    loop Length [append password (pick chars random Length)]
    password
]
TWTQWWEWRTQWWTW
make-password: func [Length][
    chars: "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890"
    password: "TWTQWWEWRTQWWTW"
    loop Length [append password (pick chars random Length)]
    password
]
TWTQWWEWRTQWWTWQTTQQ
make-password: func [Length][
    chars: "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890"
    password: "TWTQWWEWRTQWWTWQTTQQ"
    loop Length [append password (pick chars random Length)]
    password
]
TWTQWWEWRTQWWTWQTTQQTRRTT
make-password: func [Length][
    chars: "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890"
    password: "TWTQWWEWRTQWWTWQTTQQTRRTT"
    loop Length [append password (pick chars random Length)]
    password
]
```

To copy the string to `password` rather than point to it, try this instead:

```
make-password: func[Length] [
    chars: "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890"
    password: copy ""
    loop Length [append password (pick chars random Length)]
    password
]
```

Comment: Your answer is rigth but @HostileFork gave a more profound answer.

Comment: @Caridorc I was hoping he would.

Comment: @Caridorc Glad you found it useful.  I've expanded upon it a little to make a couple of other issues more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Not having enough reputation to comment on HostileFork's answer, I react this way. It's about your "Related Note", that points me to something I had never been aware of.

"Some argue" suggests you are not amongst them, but nevertheless you’ve made me think I better write **str: make string! 0** and **blk: make block! 0** from now on, not only within functions. The sizing hint has always puzzled me. Are there any recommendations for what to choose here in case you have no idea of the final magnitude? (Not less than your minimal expectation of course, and also not more than the maximum.)