# Initialization in Rebol/Red language

Tags: variables, initialization, rebol, red

In example given on http://business-programming.com/business_programming.html#section-2.6 :

```
REBOL []
items: copy []               ; WHY NOT JUST "items: []"
prices: copy []              ; WHY NOT JUST "prices: []"
append items "Screwdriver"
append prices "1.99"
append items "Hammer"
append prices "4.99"
append items "Wrench"
append prices "5.99"
```

Why should one do `items: copy []` and not `items: []` ? Also should this be done for all variable initializations or are there some selective types for which this is needed?

Edit: I find that following code works all right:

```
REBOL []
items: []   
prices: []  
append items "Screwdriver"
append prices "1.99"
append items "Hammer"
append prices "4.99"
append items "Wrench"
append prices "5.99"

probe items
probe prices

items: []   
prices: []  
append items "Screwdriver"
append prices "1.99"
append items "Hammer"
append prices "4.99"
append items "Wrench"
append prices "5.99"

probe items
probe prices
```

Output is ok:

```
["Screwdriver" "Hammer" "Wrench"]
["1.99" "4.99" "5.99"]
["Screwdriver" "Hammer" "Wrench"]
["1.99" "4.99" "5.99"]
```

But not following:

```
REBOL []

myfn: func [][
    items: []   
    prices: []  
    append items "Screwdriver"
    append prices "1.99"
    append items "Hammer"
    append prices "4.99"
    append items "Wrench"
    append prices "5.99" ]

do myfn
probe items
probe prices

do myfn
probe items
probe prices
```

Output is duplicated here:

```
["Screwdriver" "Hammer" "Wrench"]
["1.99" "4.99" "5.99"]
["Screwdriver" "Hammer" "Wrench" "Screwdriver" "Hammer" "Wrench"]
["1.99" "4.99" "5.99" "1.99" "4.99" "5.99"]
```

Is the problem only when initialization is in a function?

Apparently, all variables in a function are taken as global variables by default and created only once at start. It seems that the language is converting my function to:

```
items: []   
prices: []  
myfn: func [][
    append items "Screwdriver"
    append prices "1.99"
    append items "Hammer"
    append prices "4.99"
    append items "Wrench"
    append prices "5.99" ]
```

Now the response of multiple calls to myfn is understandable. 
Global functions created in a loop are also created only once.

Comment: It might help if you read through the answer to ["Why do functions have memory in Rebol?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25935648/211160)  But as that answer notes, the new semantics in Ren-C will not allow you to do the append without the copy, because `[]` is an array in source and it will be locked.

Comment: It becomes quite clear on reading the link. Can someone explain this in terms of 'mutable' and 'immuatable' or is that not relevant here?

Comment: Pl see my edit in question above also.

Comment: It is not from being in a function, it's from running the same line of code more than once.  You get accumulative behavior with a loop as well, e.g. **loop 2 [data: [] append data 'something]**.  While some would read that and think each iteration of the loop would get a new empty block via the assignment **data: []**, there is only one instance of *that* particular block.  So the second time through the loop it will be **data: [something]** in R3-Alpha and Red.  As I've said before, my own opinion (implemented in Ren-C) is that source series should be locked from modification to avoid errors.

Comment: Very well explained.

Comment: *"Global functions created in a loop are also created only once."* -> actually, if you say **loop 2 [foo: func [x] [print x] foo "hello"]** the FUNC function will run each time through the loop, making a unique distinct (but identically-behaving) function.  However, if you said **loop 2 compose [foo: (func [x] [print x]) foo "hello"]** it would do the composition to create the function just one time.  This function would have a unique pointer/reference, and then the loop would assign that same unique reference.  It's a strange way to write software, if you haven't noticed yet.  :-)

Comment: Is there any option by which all variables in a function/loop are local by default and global only if so declared?

Answer (score 2):

The `copy []` is not needed in this script because when it's run again, all prior references to the series `items` and `prices` will be created anew.

But if there's a possibility that the `items: []` is going to run more than once inside the same script, then you need to copy to make sure you create a new series each time, and not just reference the existing series.

Comment: So, `items: []` should not be part of a function in which `items` may be getting modified, else it will affect next calls to that function. Am I right?